# Javascript, creating a template for a textfield with subscript and superscript

Tags: javascript, html

I am rather new to JavaScript. In my experimentation with some sample code, I have created an html file which contains a table. In one of the table data fields I have a text type field. Is there a way to make a button that inserts a pre-defined template for entry that allows for manipulation? aka I press a button "money" that inputs an additional formatted text to "$0.00".

so for example

```
function input_button(){
    var template = "$0.00"
    var my_txt = document.getElementById("money");
    my_txt.value += Template;
```

On a side note, what if I wanted to use subscript and superscript? I have tried utilizing the .sup() and  .sub() methods, but it just inserts the tags and doesn't alter the aesthetics of the text.  ( so in the table, it looks like

```
 <sub> things to be subscript </sub>
```

opposed to 
 <sub>things to be subscript</sub>

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: @j08691 sorry, updated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with any way to template text formats, so you might just have to hard code in the logic. As to your second question, when you use the .sup and .sub methods, are you inserting the result in the inner html? For example:

```
function helloWorldSuper(){
    var str = "Hello World";
    var result = str.sup();
    document.getElementById("tableCell").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: Would inner html alter all of the text within the text field or just specific characters? What if I have other data I do not want to alter?

Comment: You would need to preserve what's already there then. document.getElementById("tableCell").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tableCell").innerHTML + result;

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused but I'm making the assumption that you are trying to add sup/sub script via innerHTML?

```
var template = "<span class='supStyle'>$0.00</span>"
```

CSS:

```
.supStyle{vertical-align:top;font-size:smaller;}
```

Or, you can use a forloop:

```
mySup = document.getElementsByClassName("supStyle");
for (var i=0;i<mySup.length;i++)
{
mySup[i].style.verticalAlign = "sub";
mySup[i].style.fontSize = "smaller";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply a mask to the input field in order to auto-format values with a template you will need to listen to input key press events and handle according to your mask. There are some scripts that already do this, like [Masked Input Plugin for jQuery](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

If you want the input text to just have `$0.00` as an initial value, it's quite easy to do.
You can create and insert a row into the table via JavaScript like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button id="insertRowButton">Insert</button>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Text</th><th>Input</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableBody">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script>
            (function() {
                // Elements used
                var tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody'),
                    insertRowButton = document.getElementById('insertRowButton');

                // Create a new row template
                function createRow() {
                    var tr = document.createElement('tr'),
                        tdText = document.createElement('td'),
                        tdInput = document.createElement('td'),
                        sub = document.createElement('sub'),
                        input = document.createElement('input'),
                        text = document.createTextNode('This is a text node '),
                        subscriptText = document.createTextNode('with subscript');
                    sub.appendChild(subscriptText);
                    tdText.appendChild(text);
                    tdText.appendChild(sub);
                    input.value = '$0.00';
                    tdInput.appendChild(input);
                    tr.appendChild(tdText);
                    tr.appendChild(tdInput);
                    return tr;
                }

                // Insert a new row into table
                function insertRow() {
                    var tr = createRow();
                    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
                }

                // Bind events
                insertRowButton.addEventListener('click', insertRow);
            }());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is it at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ck7qargw/